# Retrieve a verifier from a callback URL using Java

Tags: java, oauth

I am new to java development environment. Any help will be really appreciated.

I have an orkut app developed to work on my mobile application. It uses OAuth 2.0. I succeeded in

1. getting the authorizationURL
2. launching a browser with this URL
3. logging in using userid and password
4. Redirected to callbackURL.

   I want to extract the "oauth_verifier" parameter from the URL into a variable in my javacode for further authentication. Or please help me to get the callbackURL **with parameters** from the browser.

Please help me !!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setWebViewClient method of webview and then implement a new webViewClient, then you can access full url by using onPageFinished method. see code below.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
    {
        if (url.contains("#access_token=")) //I am looking for #access_token= hash, you can look for any parameter here
        {
            String accessToken = url.substring(url.indexOf("#access_token=") + 14, url.length()); //14 is my "#access_token=" length, yours will be different
            writeAccessTokenToFile(accessToken); //this method is your method
            loadApplication(); //then load you application logic, this is your method too
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: But this method seems to be applicable only for android developers. :(

Comment: you are right, it is for android development, what framework are you using for server side java development?